# Missing step in proving that $[L:K] = n \Rightarrow$ there are precisely $n$ distinct $K$-monomorphisms $L \rightarrow N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, proof-explanation

The following is a proof that $[L:K] = n \Rightarrow$ there are precisely $n$ distinct $K$-monomorphisms $L \rightarrow N$, where $N$ is the normal closure of $L:K$.

[image]

My concern is that the author states "by induction there are precisely $s$ distinct $K( \alpha )$-monomorphisms $p_1, ..., p_s : L \rightarrow N$". Shouldn't the induction step allow us to state only that "by induction there are precisely $s$ distinct $K( \alpha )$-monomorphisms $p_1, ..., p_s : L \rightarrow N'$, where $N'$ is the normal closure of $L:K( \alpha )$"?

Such a problem could be solved by noticing that $N' \subseteq N$, though the only proof I know of the latter fact is quite long and messy. Is there an easier way to understand how the statement made by the author is correct?

---

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: The normal closure $N$ of $L$ over $K$ is the smallest normal extension of $K$ that contains $L$. In particular, since $K(\alpha)\subseteq L$, then $N$ Is a normal extension of $K$ (and hence of $K(\alpha)$) that contains $L$, and so the normal closure of $L$ over $K(\alpha)$ is contained in $N$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin. Did you mean to say that $N'$, the normal closure of $L:K( \alpha )$, is a normal extension of $K( \alpha )$ and thus a normal extension of $K$?

Comment: No, that would not follow; for example, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, but not of $\mathbb{Q}$. I meant what I said: $N$ is the normal closure of $L$ over $K$, hence by definition is the smallest normal extension of $K$ that contains $L$. Being a normal extension of $K$, and since it contains $K(\alpha)$, it is also a normal extension of $K(\alpha)$. So $N$ is a normal extension of $K(\alpha)$ that contains $L$, and therefore must contain the normal closure of $L$ over $K(\alpha)$ (your $N'$). Hence, $N'\subseteq N$, as desired.

Comment: Also that theorem is true only in separable extensions (for example in perfect fields). In this case Galois and normal are the same. And, by the theorem, $N/K$ is Galois is the same as $K$ is the fixed field of $Aut(N/K)$, in which case we know all the minimal polynomials. (in the inseparable case $\mathbf{F}_p(t)/\mathbf{F}_p(t^p)$ is normal and it doesn't have any non-trivial automorphism, as the minimal polynomial is $X^p-t^p = (X-t)^p$)

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a field $R$ is the "normal closure of $M$ over $F$" (or in your notation, "normal closure of $M\colon F$") if and only if:

1. $R$ is an extension of $F$ that contains $M$ ($F\subseteq M\subseteq R$);
2. $R$ is a normal extension of $F$ ($R\colon F$ is normal); and
3. $R$ is the smallest normal extension of $F$ that contains $M$ (if $S$ is any field with $F\subseteq M\subseteq S$ and $S\colon F$ is normal, then $R\subseteq S$).

*Added:* The above assumes we are working over a particular algebraic closure; probably better would be to replace the inclusions with $F$-embeddings, to allow for “up to isomorphism” situations.

In your set-up, $N'$ is the normal closure of $L$ over $K(\alpha)$, and $N$ is the normal closure of $L$ over $K$. You want to show that $N'\subseteq N$. To that end, it is enough (by part 3 of the definition) to show that $N$ is a normal extension of $K(\alpha)$ that contains $L$.

Indeed, recall that if $F\subseteq F'\subseteq M$, and $M$ is normal over $F$, then it is also normal over $F'$ (the converse does not hold, even if you assume $F'$ is normal over $F$). In particular, since $N$ contains $K(\alpha)$ and is normal over $K$, $N$ is also normal over $K(\alpha)$. Since $K(\alpha)\subseteq L\subseteq N$, then $N$ is a normal extension of $K(\alpha)$ that contains $L$. By definition, $N$ contains the normal closure of $L$ over $K(\alpha)$, namely $N'$. Thus, $N'\subseteq N$, as desired.

---

In comments, the OP provides a different definition of “normal closure”, where we have

3’. $R$ is the smallest normal extension of $F$ that contains $M$: if $M\subseteq S\subseteq R$, and $S$ is normal over $M$, then $S=R$. In other words, no proper subextension of $R:M$ can be normal over $F$.

That would account for the larger difficulty alluded to by the OP.

Comment: Your definition seems a bit odd to me. The reason being that outside of $ \mathbb{C}$ normal closures need not be unique, however your definition seems to imply that they are. In my book $#3$ is replaced by "if $M \subseteq S \subseteq R$ and $S:F$ is normal, then $R = S$". Excuse my pedantry, but do you happen to know how to prove that $N' \subseteq N$ using the definition in my book?

Comment: @Leo: The definition assumes that you are either working inside a fixed algebraic closure, or else you can replace the inclusions with $F$-embeddings. As to the book, what you are saying is that your definition of “normal closure” is that  any proper subextension is not normal. That is indeed more complicated to do.

Comment: @Leo: I would want to know what your definition of “normal” is, and what properties you have established for normal extensions, in particular as they relate to extensions of homomorphisms. It may be simply that since $N$ is normal over $K(\alpha)$, the embeddings into $N’$ can be mapped into $N$.

Comment: A field extension $L:K$ is normal if every irreducible polynomial over $K$ with a zero in $L$ splits in $L$. Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "extensions of homomorphisms" in this context.

Comment: @Leo: And you have established no other characterizations? E.g., “normal if and only if splitting field of a set of separable polynomials”?

Comment: If by characterization you mean a sufficient and necessary condition for an extension to be normal, then what you just stated would be the only example that comes to mind. If you mean instead a characteristic of a normal extension, then I've studied to many to list.

Comment: @Leo: “characterization” means a necessary and sufficient condition *(“equivalent” is the same as ‘necessary and sufficient’, so saying “sufficient and equivalent” is unnecessary repetition).

Comment: Yes, my bad. I edited my comment.

Comment: It also comes to mind that an extension $L:K$ is normal and finite if and only if the fixed field of its Galois group is $K$.

Comment: @leo: Given what you have on hand, and the definitions you are using, it seems like anything I offer would be about the same as what you posted elsewhere, not a simplification. However, a way to get around that difficulty is to strengthen your induction hypothesis to include “any given normal extension of $K$ containing $L$”.